# jQuery - select everything after certain string

Tags: jquery

Say, I have the following:

```
<textarea>
x = 1 mod 3
x = 5 mod 7
x = 2 mod 9
</textarea>
```

What I want to do with jQuery is select `3`, `7` and `9` and multiply them. `.nextUntil()` or `.nextAll()` don't seem to be much useful in this case.

Comment: Well, no: they wouldn't be; they don't work on strings, just elements. What result do you want/expect?

Comment: `3*7*9 = 189` is what I expect.

Comment: Using `.nextUntil()` and `.nextAll()` without reading docs and understanding how and what for it works is indeed not useful.

Comment: Your title doesn't really describe your question accurately.

Comment: `jQuery - selecting textarea content`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way. Provided you have the same structure.

```
var num = 1;
$('textarea').val().split(/\n/).forEach(function(x){ // split on new line and loop
   if (x) num *= x.match(/\d+$/)[0]; // then multiply it with number
});
alert(num); // the number which is required
```

Comment: Awesome! Will accept the answer as soon as possible. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Can I do `<span id='natn'></span>` and then `document.getElementById('natn').innerHTML = num;`?

Comment: @dwvaxaz of course. You can do it with jQuery also `$('#natn').text(num);`

Comment: @dwvaxaz, yes, or `document.getElementById('natn').textContent = num;` or `$('#natn').html(num);` or `$('#natn').text(num);`

Comment: @AmitJoki do you care that everything will crash and burn with numbers greater than `9` and this approach?

Comment: @AmitJoki that's much better, +1 :) By the way, `(/\n/g)` can be `(/\n/)`

Comment: o,O It will? Because I do sometimes get numbers larger than 9.

Comment: One last question. So far I'm doing it with: `$(document).ready(function(){});` but I want to run the script after the textarea since now it returns 1.

Comment: @dwvaxaz what do you mean by _to run the script after the textarea_? The code ([fiddle with updated question code](http://jsfiddle.net/k184sgpw/6/)) works "as is" with default `<textarea>` value. And because of `document.ready` it fires after DOM is ready, so, once again, default `<textarea>` value is got without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

## If you like unreadable code:

```
var num = $('textarea')[0].value.trim().split(/\n/)
  .map(function(e) { return +e.match(/(\d+$)/g) })
  .reduce(function(p,c,a,i) { return p*c });
```

## <3